# Finding Offset number of a record where my ID belongs to

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

i gave a query to sort records in pagination like:

```
SELECT title_img as image , id   FROM  videos where id<>0
     ORDER BY created DESC  LIMIT  20 OFFSET 0
```

i have 2000 total record

my question is there any way to find the offset number if we provide Id of the record using mysql Query

suppose if i enter 1094 as id the i need to get 55 as offset. 
i am using PHP on Mysql

please help me
thanx in advance..

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT count(1) FROM  videos where id < 1094
```

Comment: but we need to divid this value with per page value..rit??

Answer (score -1):

If your record ids are in non breaking sequence (means no missing numbers) from 1 to 2000, then you can apply following code.

```
ceil(record_id/limit)=offset
```

Comment: There is no such thing like "non breaking sequence"

Comment: mate this is the way we find the offset but how would you relate that to the id selection ..??

Comment: @tradebel123 can you explore your question?